# Is Flash Builder 4.7 based on Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

In Flash Builder Install New Software screen the Available Software Sites dropdown list is empty. I found a couple of posts online that says to add the update site manually. The link they give is for Indigo, http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo. Is Flash Builder built on Indigo? Is this the right site to install plugins and updates?

I'm not sure how to check what version of Eclipse Flash Builder 4.7 is built on but in the  help screen it says, "Version: 3.7.1.r37" but now where does it say Indigo.

*To sum up I just need to know the download site for my install.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Eclipse Indigo is version 3.7.x.

The names go in alphabetical order moving on one letter per release. Juno is 3.8 / 4.2, Kepler is 4.3

There is a longer list of old releases [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse)